# Remove "are you sure?" prompt when deleting comments from flag queue

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, moderation, comment-flags

### Current State

Deleting comments on a post, outside the flag queue, requires no prompt.

Deleting comments on a flagged post (whether a comment or other flag) requires confirmation *each* time. This isn't a problem if someone flags all comments, but normally "too chatty" indicates other problem comments too.

### Issues with current state

My workflow when moderating comment cleanup is to open the post in a new tab so I can more quickly delete and cleanup comments. This is annoyingly inefficient.

### Desired future state

Remove confirmation in flag queue for deleting comments.